# Конфликт с 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0' Android

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Недавно добавил в свой проект MapKit от Yandexа.

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'
```

В итоге получил вот такой ряд ошибок

> 1. Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\anton\StudioProjects\TaxiService\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\10.jar
> 2. Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
> 3. Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Мой build.gradle приложения представлен ниже

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lstu.kovalchuk.taxiservice"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зашел в официальный репизиторий примера проекта с MapKit на GitHub и увидел там аналогичную проблему. Прошел по ссылкам и увидел решение: отключить D8 в файле gradle.properties, то есть в этом файле прописать в конце `android.enableD8=false`

Comment: При попытке удалить D8 выдаёт предупреждение, но проект всё равно запускается 1. The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. 2. Use 'android.enableD8=true' to remove this warning. 3. It will be removed in AGP version 3.3.